# Is there a public queryable version of Stellar.db out there?

Tags: inflation, data

Do I need to host my own continuous instance of horizon pointed to a DB that I control in order to execute a query like:

```
SELECT SUM(balance) FROM accounts WHERE inflationdest = {inflation_destination}
```

I currently have a console app running an operation stream on the .net core SDK and would like to be able to execute that query from inside of it. 
Trying to figure out what I would need to do to make that happen.

Comment: If you do build this please let us know.  I'd love to use something like this.  Thanks!

Comment: You could use Fed.network's inflation HTTP API for this specific purpose: `https://fed.network/inflation/<account id>`.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you rather need the `core` db instead of `horizon` for your query. There is no publicly available `core` DB and I doubt that ever will be, due to unpredictable loading and security implications.

You have to set up your own Stellar Core node. It doesn't need to be a validator node. That way you'll have access to the relevant and 100% genuine network information.